# How to unselect and undo with checkboxes using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, checkbox

I have a checkbox, when the checkbox is selected I want to add int 2 to my total. Then I want to be able to unselect it and then subtract int 2 to my total.

At the moment, I cant unselect and subtract 2.

Also, my checkbox is in a button group so I need to use clearSelection() as a solution to deselect.

The code I currently have for this is (which isn't work too well):

```
monTill4ChckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(monTill4ChckBox.isSelected()){

                mondayCost= mondayCost + 2; 
            }
            else{
            mondayCost= mondayCost - 2;             
            monAftergroup.clearSelection();
            }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add item listener to the checkbox for listening check state properly.
Something like this;

```
monTill4ChckBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            if(monTill4ChckBox.isSelected()){
                mondayCost= mondayCost + 2; 
            }
            else{
                mondayCost= mondayCost - 2;             
                monAftergroup.clearSelection();
            }
            System.err.println("Counter: " + mondayCost);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I 've implemented a Sample gui and added check box and added listener which is above. And clicked many times again anda again. There were no problem.